# how to compare probabilities

Tags: probability

Problem
A Population of totally 187000 chicks, is grouped in 27'300 chicks that are protected by flattery bands and reflecting elements. The other group with 159'700 chickens are not  protected. During one year it is obeserved, that in total 800 chicks are robbed by raptors, 78 are robbed from the protected population, and 722 are robbed from the non protected population.

What is the probability, that
a) a robbed chicken is from the protected chicks? P(E2/E1)= ?
b) a robbed chicken is from the unprotected chicks? P(E2/E3)=?
c) What is the best way, to compare the probabilities from a) and b) ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn83q.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: "protected by flattery bands and reflecting elements" ??? What flattery is doing here and what is the point for the question ?

Comment: The bands are for protection. The question I asked is clear for someone, who is able to solve the problem.